# Set default role permissions during Magento installation (magerun ?)

Tags: permissions

I have Magento installation script (running `php install.php (...)`) that reinstalls Magento. However - everytime when I reinstall Mage during the development - I have to set permissions for each role individually again.

I would like to make something like
`php magerun.phar customer:create test@test.pl test123 Test Test 2`

But setting custom role permissions:

[image: Example roles to set]

Eg. `php magerun.phar role:permissions:set role_name permission_name` or anything programatically.

Do you know any way to get that?